# unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.9.1: not found unresolved dependency: de.johoop#sbt-testng-plugin;3.1.1: not found on mac

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-revolver

Facing issue after importing project to intellij.

unresolved dependency: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.9.1: not found
unresolved dependency: de.johoop#sbt-testng-plugin;3.1.1: not found

How to install above dependencies using bash.

i tried addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1") with but having syntex error as

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"io.spray"'

Answer (score 2):

The line `addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")` is not a bash command. Instead, it needs to go into e. g. `project/plugins.sbt` (or any other file with a `.sbt` extension in the `project` folder).

Comment: I tried with same but having still same error Unresolved dependencies:<ul><li> com.lightbend.sbt#sbt-aspectj;0.11.0: not found</li><li> io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.9.1: not found</li><li> de.johoop#sbt-testng-plugin;3.1.1: not found</li></ul>See complete log in file:/Users/xxxLibrary/Logs/IntelliJIdea2018.1/sbt.last.log